# How to change border color in QT

Tags: qt

In my application i need to use dark grey color border for my progress. by googling i changed the border color and background color successfully like,

```
QString st = QString ("QProgressBar::chunk {""background-color: #00B82E;""}");
st.append("QProgressBar {""border: 6px solid grey;" "border-radius: 9px;""text-align: center;""background: #00B82E;""}");
Progress->setStyleSheet(st);
```

but not able to find out the list of border color like "border: 6px solid grey;".How to find out list of colors like "6px solid grey" because i need to change another color for border

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt Style Sheets take a lot from HTML Cascading Style Sheets (CSS).

[Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#setNamedColor) for `QColor::setNamedColor` says that a color name can be one of SVG color keyword names:

> A name from the list of colors defined in the list of SVG color
>   keyword names provided by the World Wide Web Consortium; for example,
>   "steelblue" or "gainsboro". These color names work on all platforms.
>   Note that these color names are not the same as defined by the
>   Qt::GlobalColor enums, e.g. "green" and Qt::green does not refer to
>   the same color.

SVG color keyword names:
http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#ColorKeywords

Comment: It is much better to use official Qt documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html instead of researching, what styles from CSS are supported in QSS. Please, update your answer.

Comment: @SaZ:I didn't find a list of supported color keywrods there. But in another article (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#setNamedColor) Qt docs refer to SVG color keyword names (http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#ColorKeywords)